# Can't find file with python script when run via cron

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have an automated script - I mean, it runs every 10 minutes by a cronjob. 
The weird thing is: The file is always found and runs through it when I start the script by hand. But it gives me a lot of troubles when it runs by cron job.

these are the rights of the files:

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 dataloader users     181 Dec 19 12:37 Foo.after
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 dataloader users   26098 Feb 16 20:56 loader.py
> ```

this is an abstract of loader.py where it checks for Foo.after:

```
if os.path.exists(self.customer+'.after'):
            print 'customer file exists'
            f = open(self.customer+'.after')
```

Comment: Most likely the script isn't running in the directory you think it is inside the cron job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cronjob is not executing in the same directory/environment as the script.

You can address this by adjusting your cronjob:

```
* * * * * cd /home/yourdir; ./loader.py
```

OR

```
* * * * * /home/mc/dotasks.sh
```

dotasks.sh contains:

```
cd /home/yourdir
./loader.py
#anything else you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the environment configured for cron, you can dump it as a cron job itself.
* * * * * env > /yourcompletepath/envtxt
Now look for python version. Does it match. Look for PWD value. 
From here you can cd to your working folder and then use python to start your file.
Ensure that the python file is terminated properly, without any blank spaces near EOF.